# Why does logging not work with laravel 5.4 and rapid7?

Tags: php, laravel, logging

I am using laravel 5.4 and package logentries/logentries-monolog-handler 2.1 version.

When I use the monolog and use configureMonologUsing in bootstrap/app.php, logging stops working even the log file is not there in storage/logs and even there is no entry at rapid7 logentries

This the code I am using in bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) {
   $logEntriesHandler = new Monolog\Handler\LogEntriesHandler('My token');
   $monolog->pushHandler($logEntriesHandler);
});
```

And for logging in controller

```
Log::info('_message:Generated');
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I had word with rapid7 support and they said currently they don't have any library for php, They are working on it.

So, they provided me with beta version you can download it from the following link:

https://r7.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/41000000VVEY/a/3f000000Cac5/ahJpIPY.q1PSmQS.Dpr0_3F_KQaSs_RJWG.jWWJRj94

All you will need to do to get this working is to change the region and token, then this will be good to go.

To use it in your code, enter the following lines, making changes accordingly if you place it in a different location.

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/r7insight_php-master/r7insight.php';

 // The following levels are available
 $log->Debug(" ");
 $log->Info(" ");
 $log->Notice(" ");
 $log->Warn(" ");
 $log->Crit(" ");
 $log->Error(" ");
 $log->Alert(" ");
 $log->Emerg(" ");
```

So per the above you can only log the levels that are called. It will not log all events, only when it is called.